# Qt PowerVR driver mouse pointer unavailable

Tags: qt, embedded, mouse, powervr-sgx

I am not trying to spam here just trying to be more specific about the issue of Qt mouse pointer not being available for PowerVR. So I hope someone will have a answer to my question.

Qt PowerVR driver needs to be compiled with QT_NO_QWS_CURSOR which stops usage of mouse but still leaves room for touch screens.

I just want to know why this is needed is it because of a hardware limitation or is it just a incomplete driver.

Thank you very much for assistanse well in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried that driver, I just saw the code. I suppose that is only used for performance reasons. Placing a pointer requires Qt to do its own software compositing over hardware accelerated OpenGL graphics, reducing performance.

It is possible that simply omitting that definition your pointer appears, or anyway making it appear requires only to instantiate it. Consider anyway that if simple software cursor is used, it may not be good when placed over OpenGL surfaces. You might need an implementation using platform specific structures which you might have or might not. Sorry if I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found a few in internet where some people has activated the mouse yet it is not being visible or whole display going blank. I guess the best way is to try something on my own.